# Non maximum suppression from google cloud vision response nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, numpy, computer-vision

So I'd like to see if it's possible to implement non max suppression in nodejs from google clouds vision API responses, for example a response looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "mid": "/m/09728",
    "languageCode": "",
    "name": "Bread",
    "score": 0.8558391332626343,
    "boundingPoly": {
      "vertices": [],
      "normalizedVertices": [
        {
          "x": 0.010737711563706398,
          "y": 0.26679491996765137
        },
        {
          "x": 0.9930269718170166,
          "y": 0.26679491996765137
        },
        {
          "x": 0.9930269718170166,
          "y": 0.7275580167770386
        },
        {
          "x": 0.010737711563706398,
          "y": 0.7275580167770386
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "mid": "/m/052lwg6",
    "languageCode": "",
    "name": "Baked goods",
    "score": 0.6180902123451233,
    "boundingPoly": {
      "vertices": [],
      "normalizedVertices": [
        {
          "x": 0.010737711563706398,
          "y": 0.26679491996765137
        },
        {
          "x": 0.9930269718170166,
          "y": 0.26679491996765137
        },
        {
          "x": 0.9930269718170166,
          "y": 0.7275580167770386
        },
        {
          "x": 0.010737711563706398,
          "y": 0.7275580167770386
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "mid": "/m/02wbm",
    "languageCode": "",
    "name": "Food",
    "score": 0.5861617922782898,
    "boundingPoly": {
      "vertices": [],
      "normalizedVertices": [
        {
          "x": 0.321802020072937,
          "y": 0.2874892055988312
        },
        {
          "x": 0.999139130115509,
          "y": 0.2874892055988312
        },
        {
          "x": 0.999139130115509,
          "y": 0.6866284608840942
        },
        {
          "x": 0.321802020072937,
          "y": 0.6866284608840942
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

So actually the bounding box that should be on the outside is food like so:

[image]

I've found examples in Python to do [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python/), but that means I need to use subprocesses in Node to execute the python script and then pull back the response, which kinda feels a bit dirty.

Obviously those box values from google need multiplying by the image height and width, so if we assume it's 288 X 512 for example:

```
      const left = Math.round(vertices[0].x * 288);
      const top = Math.round(vertices[0].y * 512);
      const width = Math.round((vertices[2].x * 288)) - left;
      const height = Math.round((vertices[2].y * 512)) - top;
```

My adapted script is like so(just hard codes the threshold and takes the array of boxes from the command line):

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import sys
import json

# Malisiewicz et al.
def non_max_suppression_fast():
    overlapThresh = 0.3
    boxes = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    # if there are no boxes, return an empty list
    if len(boxes) == 0:
        return []

    # if the bounding boxes integers, convert them to floats --
    # this is important since we'll be doing a bunch of divisions
    if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
        boxes = boxes.astype("float")

    # initialize the list of picked indexes 
    pick = []

    # grab the coordinates of the bounding boxes
    x1 = boxes[:,0]
    y1 = boxes[:,1]
    x2 = boxes[:,2]
    y2 = boxes[:,3]

    # compute the area of the bounding boxes and sort the bounding
    # boxes by the bottom-right y-coordinate of the bounding box
    area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
    idxs = np.argsort(y2)

    # keep looping while some indexes still remain in the indexes
    # list
    while len(idxs) > 0:
        # grab the last index in the indexes list and add the
        # index value to the list of picked indexes
        last = len(idxs) - 1
        i = idxs[last]
        pick.append(i)

        # find the largest (x, y) coordinates for the start of
        # the bounding box and the smallest (x, y) coordinates
        # for the end of the bounding box
        xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

        # compute the width and height of the bounding box
        w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
        h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

        # compute the ratio of overlap
        overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

        # delete all indexes from the index list that have
        idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
            np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

    # return only the bounding boxes that were picked using the
    # integer data type
    return boxes[pick].astype("int")
```

Is anyone able to give me any pointers here please? I'm pretty sure it's just about calculating the total area of the each box, but I can't quite get my brain around it.

Comment: So might have found it, tensorflow has a js lib https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#image.nonMaxSuppression

I'll post if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so actually this is pretty simple if you use Tensorflow.js - use the following function to take the response from google vision:

**Note 288 and 512 are my image width and height you'll need to setup your own.**

```
function nonMaxSuppression(objects){

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      // Loop through the objects and convert the vertices into the right format.
      for (let index = 0; index < objects.length; index++) {
        const verts = objects[index].boundingPoly.normalizedVertices;

        // As above note 288 and 512 are image width and image height for me.
        const left = Math.round(verts[0].x * 288);
        const top = Math.round(verts[0].y * 512);
        const width = Math.round((verts[2].x * 288)) - left;
        const height = Math.round((verts[2].y * 512)) - top;
        // we need an array of boxes AND an array of scores
        this.boxes.push([left, top, width, height]);
        this.scores.push(objects[index].score);
      }
      // Params are boxes, scores, max number of boxes to select.
      const theBox = tf.image.nonMaxSuppression(this.boxes, this.scores, 2);
      // the function returns the box number that matched from this.boxes, seems like it's not zero based at least in my tests so we need to - 1 to get the index from the original array.
      resolve(theBox.id -1 );
    });
}
```

Ta-dah banana!